# Mapping using a custom function with 2 or more arguments using purrr

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dplyr, purrr

I am building an insurance rater in R. I want to build a single (sometimes complicated) function with several arguments and then iterate this function over each policyholder (data row). I will have to build about 200 of these functions for this project. The function works fine, and it just essentially looks up values in the rate table and adds or multiplies when, what, and how I need it to. My question is how can I map, or loop, or otherwise iterate this function when I have 2 or more arguments being fed into the function directly from the data frame?

I thought my coding worked, but I then realized that map (or map_dbl) only pulled in the first element of the second argument in my function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)

#dummy data frames that represent a rating table, and a policy
#holder dataset

data_frame_Rate_Table<-data.frame("Policy_Class"=c("red", "white","blue"),"Rate"=c(3,9,19),"Factor_1"= 1:3,"Factor_2"=7:9)
data_frame_Policyholders<-data.frame("Policy_number"=1:10,"Policy_Class"=rep(c("red","red","white","blue","blue"),2),"Risk"=c(rep("High",5),rep("Low",5)),"Lapse"=rep(c("Y","N"),5))

function_example<-function(x,y,z){
  Policy_Class<-x
  Risk<-y
  Lapse<-z
  Rate<-ifelse(Policy_Class=="red",
              data_frame_Rate_Table[data_frame_Rate_Table['Policy_Class']==Policy_Class,"Rate"]*data_frame_Rate_Table[data_frame_Rate_Table['Policy_Class']==Policy_Class,"Factor_1"]+
              (ifelse(Risk=="High",3,1))*data_frame_Rate_Table[data_frame_Rate_Table['Policy_Class']==Policy_Class,"Factor_2"]+ifelse(Lapse=="Y",10,0),
        ifelse(Policy_Class=="white",
              data_frame_Rate_Table[data_frame_Rate_Table['Policy_Class']==Policy_Class,"Rate"]*data_frame_Rate_Table[data_frame_Rate_Table['Policy_Class']==Policy_Class,"Factor_1"]+
              (ifelse(Risk=="High",5,1))*data_frame_Rate_Table[data_frame_Rate_Table['Policy_Class']==Policy_Class,"Factor_2"]+ifelse(Lapse=="Y",15,0),
        ifelse(Policy_Class=="blue",
              data_frame_Rate_Table[data_frame_Rate_Table['Policy_Class']==Policy_Class,"Rate"]*data_frame_Rate_Table[data_frame_Rate_Table['Policy_Class']==Policy_Class,"Factor_1"]+
                (ifelse(Risk=="High",10,1))*data_frame_Rate_Table[data_frame_Rate_Table['Policy_Class']==Policy_Class,"Factor_2"]+ifelse(Lapse=="Y",33,0))))
    Rate
    }
```

I tried:

```
result<-map_dbl(data_frame_Policyholders$Class,function_example, data_frame_Policyholders$Risk,data_frame_Policyholders$Lapse)
```

But this is not what I need.

The expected results are:

```
#copy and paste this coding into R to get the actual 
#values that should go into the vector
function_example("red","High","Y")
function_example("red","High","N")
function_example("red","Low","Y")
function_example("red","Low","N")
function_example("white","High","Y")
function_example("white","High","N")
function_example("white","Low","Y")
function_example("white","Low","N")
function_example("blue","High","Y")
function_example("blue","High","N")
function_example("blue","Low","Y")
function_example("blue","Low","N")
```

But I obviously cannot type out each combination

I need the function to iterate over each policyholder and produce the result in a numeric vector that lines up. Can `purrr` even do this? Is there a better way to go here?

Comment: `purrr::map_dbl` only passes one argument, I think you need `pmap`, as in `with(data_frame_Policyholders, purrr::pmap_dbl(list(Policy_Class, Risk, Lapse), function_example))`. (There are other `pmap_*` variants.)

Comment: Similarly in base R: `with(data_frame_Policyholders, Map(function_example, Class, Risk, Lapse))`

Comment: Actually, `Map` will return a list, you can use `mapply` instead: `with(data_frame_Policyholders, mapply(function_example, Policy_Class, Risk, Lapse))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the first thing is to read data as characters and not factors. Second is since you have multiple inputs to your function you'll need `pmap` instead of only `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data_frame_Policyholders %>%
    mutate(new = pmap_dbl(list(Policy_Class, Risk, Lapse), function_example))


#   Policy_number Policy_Class Risk Lapse new
#1              1          red High     Y  34
#2              2          red High     N  24
#3              3        white High     Y  73
#4              4         blue High     N 147
#5              5         blue High     Y 180
#6              6          red  Low     N  10
#7              7          red  Low     Y  20
#8              8        white  Low     N  26
#9              9         blue  Low     Y  99
#10            10         blue  Low     N  66
```

**data**

```
data_frame_Rate_Table<- data.frame(Policy_Class = c("red", "white","blue"),
    Rate=c(3,9,19),"Factor_1"= 1:3,Factor_2=7:9, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data_frame_Policyholders <- data.frame(Policy_number . = 1:10,
  Policy_Class=rep(c("red","red","white","blue","blue"),2),
  Risk=c(rep("High",5),rep("Low",5)), 
  Lapse=rep(c("Y","N"),5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your coding is short and super efficient. GREATLY appreciated!!!!